# Easy question about sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Im reading through terence tao's Analysis2 book and came across the following page describing the sup norm metric.

[image]

I dont understand the example at the end. The difference $|x_i - y_i|$ refers to the $i$-th index of in this case $(1,6)$ and $(4,2)$. Why does this not result in the $sup(|1-4|=3,|6-2|=4)$. And second, why in the example is the supremum of (5,2) equal to 7 instead of the maximum of the numbers 5 and 2, which would be 5?

Comment: I agree, both of those seem like mistakes to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is clearly a mistake. The first one is taking
$d_{l^\infty}((1,4), (6,2) = \max\{5,2\}$
instead of
$d_{l^\infty}((1,6), (4,2) = \max\{3,4\}$
and the second one is not actually taking the Maximum, but the sum, which would be the $l_1$ norm.

I guess they wanted to give an example of a different norm than the euclidian norm, but they mixed up $l_1$ and $l_\infty$ in the process.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. MaoWao's answer is equally helpful, but I accepted this one because it was faster. I needed some metric to make a decision ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your are right, this is an error. Instead it should be
$$
d_{l^\infty}((1,6),(4,2))=\sup\{3,4\}=4.
$$
This error has already been recorded in the list of errata, which you can find here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-ii/